# GraphQL : query returns no result with no error

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

What could make a GraphGL Query return no result? Here, I have a component that receives the result of a query in its props via the compose() function of Apollo-React. For a reason I don't understand, the query returns no result for some $companyId and the component do not get the wished object in its props. With other given $companyId it works well.

The error object in props is set to 'undefined'.

When played independently (in the GraphiQl or the Graphcool console), the query works perfectly and returns a result.

When I remove the "aliasMail" field in the query, then it works fine all the time (for all given $companyId).

*types.graphql*

```
type Company @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  name: String
  dateCreation: DateTime
  dateUpdate: DateTime
  active: Boolean @defaultValue(value: true)
  aliasMail: String @defaultValue(value: "")
  defaultClientAccountLabel: String @defaultValue(value: "")
  defaultSupplierAccountLabel: String @defaultValue(value: "")
```

*queries.js*

```
query getCompanyForAliasEmailEditForm($companyId: ID) {
  Company(id: $companyId) {
    id
    name
    aliasMail
  }
}
```

*EmailSettingsContainer.jsx*

```
import { compose, graphql } from "react-apollo";
import Queries from "../../queries/queries";
import EmailSettings from '../../components/Email/EmailSettings';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EmailSettingsContainer extends Component {
  ...
  render(){
  return <EmailSettings
      companyToEdit={this.props.company}
    />
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(Queries.getCompanyForAliasEmailEditForm, { name: "company" })
)(EmailSettingsContainer);
```

*Console*

```
when it works:

PROPS : {companyToEdit: {…}, update: ƒ, sendNotification: ƒ, match: {…}, location: {…}, …}
  companyToEdit:
    Company:
     aliasMail: "CHTIHOUSE"
     id: "cje734xv29fzw0112pn6oxvt1"
     name: "CHTIHOUSE"
     __typename: "Company"
 Symbol(id): "Company:cje734xv29fzw0112pn6oxvt1"
  error: undefined

 when it do not works:

 PROPS :  {companyToEdit: {…}, update: ƒ, sendNotification: ƒ, match: {…}, location: {…}, …}
   companyToEdit:    (Nothing)
     error: undefined
```

Comment: You are using a named query called "company". When you console log that there should be a property "Company" after the query has loaded. Did you check the outcome?
You can also use the browser to check what you get from the server. E.g. Chrome network tab

Comment: Thanks for your support Locco0_0. I looked at the network tab. There is a bundle.js file called with a 304 status. Type is "fetch". Your comment led me to look at 'data.networkStatus' in the Apollo doc. Status is 1 here, which correspond to "loading: The query has never been run before and the request is now pending."

Comment: I finally got my answer to this issue: it is a problem of loading data !! For the $companyId that crashed this is because the data were not already in cache and had to be retrieved from the server. It takes some time and my component was rendering before the query was successful. I had no loading logic which led to a make my component crash.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit (it's still visible in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49169024/revisions)) -- your question should remain a question, and if you have an answer, please post that as an answer instead. Accepting your own answer is fine, though you can't do that immediately.

Comment: @tripleee you're right, I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I did not manage the 'loading data': while for other companyId the query result was already in cache, for others, the query had to get the data from the server. Rendering the component before the data is loaded was leading to my component crashing (as the data was not available yet).

Updating my component as follow solved my problem :

*EmailSettingsContainer.jsx*

```
import { compose, graphql } from "react-apollo";
import Queries from "../../queries/queries";
import EmailSettings from '../../components/Email/EmailSettings';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EmailSettingsContainer extends Component {
  ...
  render(){
    if (this.props.company.loading) {
      return ( <div>Loading</div> )
    } else {
      return (
        <EmailSettings
          companyToEdit={this.props.company}
          update={values => this.save(values)}
          sendNotification={this.props.sendNotification}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(Queries.getCompanyForAliasEmailEditForm, { name: "company"}),
)(EmailSettingsContainer);
```